# SQL - как получить доступ к таблице, полученной в результате запроса, из другого запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, select

Есть следующая таблица:

**Таблица 1.**

```
INSERT INTO strings
    (`str1`, `str2`, `num`)
VALUES
    ('строка1', 'строка2', 7),
    ('строка1', 'строка3', 7),
    ('строка1', 'строка4', 4),
    ('строка2', 'строка1', 3),
    ('строка2', 'строка3', 6),
    ('строка3', 'строка4', 7)
;
```

Из которой нужно получить такую таблицу:

**Таблица 2.**

```
str1    str2
строка1 строка2
строка1 строка3
строка2 строка3
строка3 строка4
```

То есть для каждой строки `"str1"` вывести `"str2"` в том случае, если паре `str1` и `str2` соответствует максимальный `"num"` для текущего `"str1"`.

В примере максимальный `"num"` для `"строка1"` = 7, соответственно выводятся `строка1 строка2` и `строка1 строка3`. Ну и так далее.

Задача очень простая, и очень просто решается, если таблица `"strings"` существует в базе данных.

**Решение.**

```
    SELECT str1, str2 from strings
    WHERE num IN
    (SELECT max(u.num) from strings u group by u.str1)
```

Однако проблема возникает в том случае, если таблица `"strings"` не находится в базе данных, а получается из другого запроса, а именно:

**Проблема.**

```
SELECT strings.str1, strings.str2 FROM
(
  ...

) strings -- та самая таблица strings
WHERE strings.num IN -- тут доступ к колонке num есть, все работает
  (SELECT max(u.num) FROM strings u GROUP BY u.str1) -- тут ошибка, table strings doesn't exist
```

Собственно, как можно решить такую проблему? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59439/discussion-on-question-by-pashakrizskiy-sql------).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, можно использовать переменные для нумерации сток и обернуть все в еще один подзапрос.

```
SELECT
    strings2.str1,
    strings2.str2
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        @rn:=CASE
            WHEN @str1 = str1 THEN @rn + 1
            ELSE 1
         END AS row_number,
        @str1:= strings.str1 AS str1,
        strings.str2
    FROM
       (
        ...
        ) strings
    order by strings.str1, strings.num desc, strings.str2
    ) strings2
WHERE strings2.row_number = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL с помощью переменных можно вывести максимальные показатели для группы наряду с индивидуальными строками. после чего можно будет сравнить в строке максимальный и текущий показатель. Получать максимумы надо в самом подзапросе, примерно так:

```
SELECT strings.str1, strings.str2 FROM
(
   SELECT str1, ..., @tmp:=xx num,
          @mtmp:=if(@cname!=str1,@tmp,@mtmp) max_num, /* Если группа сменилась, сохраняем 
              текущее значение (максимум) иначе оставляем сохраненное ранее */
          @cname:=str1  /* сохраняем группу */
     FROM ..... ,
          (select @cname:='',@mtmp:=NULL) X /* Инициализация переменных */
 /* Сортировка по полю по которому мы хотели бы группировать и по тому
    для которого будем получать максимум */
    ORDER BY str1, num desc

) strings
where num=max_num
```

Конкретно в приведенном вами примере на sqlfiddle есть нюанс, по непонятной мне причине значение колонки tmp, выводимое на клиента и сохраняемой в переменной имеют разную точность, поэтому пришлось округлить при присвоении @mtmp.

[Пример на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02f02/357)